# rails caching + ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails app that shows users posts. Users posts can be sorted in many ways, paginated, categorized, etc. I am doing all of these clicks over ajax.

However, everytime I click a category or a sortby param or a new page, it loads the ENTIRE request again and then returns it in the way specified. Is there any way to cache my first results and THEN sort, paginate, categorize quickly?

Comment: What do your views and controllers look like? I think if we saw those it would be a lot faster for you to get an answer. Also, what do you mean by "ENTIRE" request? Is it SQL performing an inefficent query or just a page rendering?

Comment: We do advanced matching techniques for our clients that are based on alot of criteria including location, industry, specific preferences set in their profile, etc etc also we perform an algorithm that scores each match. It does all of this each time a new parameter is loaded (for example, `?page=2` it would do it all over again). Basically, all the queries take place in the controller while the scoring takes place in the model.

Comment: Well have you read through the Rails caching guide? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html It seems like you can cache some of your SQL and the fragments that make up your page as well.

Comment: It seems as though I've got caching to work, however, now I can't get out of it. I have an old view saved and it won't load any changes in my controller or view. How can I clear this or force expiration?

Comment: Expiration will work if you are using memcached. [Newrelic](http://railslab.newrelic.com/) has some videos on Rails caching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to enhance the performance, a better way is to use memcache. If you have memcache installed and implemented in your rails app, you can cache that query for a certain period of time without actually querying the database again instead it will fetch directly from memory again, thus it improved performance greatly. You may want to check out https://github.com/nkallen/cache-money.

Comment: what about caching a query and also caching many manipulations on that query? Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is a question of using AJAX vs a non-AJAX javascript implementation.

When using Ajax, the question you should ask yourself is, does this action require more information or logic from the server? If the answer is no and you can do it using only the information you have already loaded on the client browser, you should try and implement it using Javascript.

In this case, there are plenty of solutions for javascript sorting out there. For example, if you want a simple table-like sorting (your table could be invisible) you could use something like this plugin: http://yoast.com/articles/sortable-table/

If you're looking for a more custom solution, you could write the javascript by hand, this post: [Sort <div> elements using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552888/sort-div-elements-using-jquery) gives a good starting point.

Hope that helps!